# Shopware 6: How to get all custom field data in storefront?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to display all the custom fields defined in the product on the product detail page. But the problem is that all the data I get is the technical name and value.

```
{
    "HS_code": "08477548",
    "length": 30
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I also get the label and the position as defined in the backend as you can see in this picture.

[custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFJb9.png)

I want to loop through the custom fields to display them. And because there is no way of knowing which custom fields you get back I can't define the labels on the go myself.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to specify your request. It seems like the custom field contains 2 values, the thing you want to be displayed and a technical part. When you call the custom field, it just prints out everything saved within the custom field. So you have to call the first value to get only that printed out.